# How to share EF6 objects in code-first

Tags: c#, associations, entity-framework-6, cardinality

I am just starting to teach myself Entity Framework (6) from the code-first scenario. My problem is I don't understand how to correctly instruct EF that certain entities may be shared among other entities.

Here's a very simple scenario with a three-level tree structure. Class `A` objects owns class `B` objects, which owns, or references, class `C` objects:

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<B> Bees { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return Id; }
}

public class B
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<C> Cees { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return Id; }
}

public class C
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return Id; }
}
```

I now create a scenario where a single `A` object owns five `B` objects which, in turn, *shares* a collection of five `C` objects. Here's the DbContext I've used:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }

    public DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // SHOULD I INSTRUCT EF HOW TO HANDLE THIS HERE?
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public Context(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

And here's some simple code to set up this scenario:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new Context(@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=TestEF6.Collections; Integrated Security=true");
        var sharedCees = createCees("A1.B1", 5, context);
        context.As.Add(new A { Id = "A1", Bees = createBees("A1", 5, sharedCees) });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private static ICollection<B> createBees(string aId, int count, ICollection<C> cees = null)
    {
        var list = new List<B>();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var id = aId + ".B" + (i + 1);
            list.Add(new B { Id = id, Cees = cees ?? createCees(id, count) });
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static ICollection<C> createCees(string bId, int count, Context saveInContext = null)
    {
        var list = new List<C>();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var id = bId + ".C" + (i+1);
            var c = new C {Id = id};
            list.Add(c);
            if (saveInContext != null)
                saveInContext.Cs.Add(c);
        }
        if (saveInContext != null)
            saveInContext.SaveChanges();
        return list;
    }
}
```

As EF creates the database ('TestEF6.SharedEntities') it assumes that `A -> B`, as well as `B -> C` are one-to-many relationships and that the child entities are components, fully owned and controlled by its master entity.

So, how do I make EF "see" that instances of `C` can be shared by instances of `B`?

In all honesty, I'm asking to get a quick start into EF. I do realize I can plow through the web and figure this out but if anyone can point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it.

Cheers

Comment: You're describing a many-to-may association between B and C. When you say that multiple Bs can have the same C you also say that C can have multiple Bs. So C should have a collection of Bs and EF will model that by a junction table BC in the database.

Comment: Thanks, Gert. That set me on the right track indeed. See my next answer please (I neeed to add some code) ...

Answer (score 0):

Gert set me on track by suggesting I'd add a collection property to the `C` class. Indeed, this is enough for EF/CF to automatically recognize the many-to-many relationship between `B` and `C`. But the whole point with code-first is to design a domain model of classes and then have EF persist them, without having to bog them down with peristency information.

I have no issues with annotating `Key` properties, or even `Required` ones. This kind of information actually makes sense in the domain model. They can be used by the domain code, but even if they're not they add clarityto the code. But to add properties that serves no other function than to act as hints to EF's auto-magic didn't seem like a very elegant solution.

So I experimented some more with the fluent API and realized I had missed the parameterless overload of `.WithMany()`. I was looking for a generic form, that would make it possible to specify the other type of a many-to-many relationship. In my mind I would then write: `modelBuilder.Entity<B>.HasMany(b => b.Cees).WithMany<B>()`. As it turned out, the parameterless overload of `WithMany()` serves this exact purpose, as type `C` in this scenario is already specified by the first `HasMany()` part.

So, to summarize, EF will recognize the many-to-many relationship between classes `B` and `C`, without the need to "litter" the `C` clas with an extra generic collection of type `B` items. So, this is how we can describe the many-to-many relationsship between the two classes without having to touch the domain classes at all:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>().HasMany(b => b.Cees).WithMany(); // <-- THE SOLUTION
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public Context(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

I realize this is very basic stuff to anyone seasoned in EF but I'll go ahead and mark this as an answer so that others may save some time looking for this information in the future.

Thanks